# LdapConnection.SendRequest() issue in the windows event log

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am having a few issues with ldap lookups in .net and hoping someone can shed some light on how LdapConnection.SendRequest() works in an AD with multiple domain controllers

A bit of background.

we use the AD/ldap connection to import user details into our system when a user logs in.
we bind to the AD using a single Ad account 'cAdmin' we would then take the username of the user that has logged in and do an ldap search on that username. if found a user we would copy some of the details over from ad into our system.

This works well, has done for years. but a customer has noticed in there event logs large numbers of calls to contact their domain controllers when ever a user logs in ( and we look up the user). i would only expect one call here and for our test systems and other clients there is only one. but there seems to be the initial call and then 6 or 7 more to a second domain controller with the account name 'c' (rather than cAdmin)

The client has load balancing on their domain controllers.

They are worried that this is some sort of virus or security risk, and i am having a hard time proving its not.

we cannot reproduce the issue here.

the first First connection is as expected

=================================

A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:

```
Security ID:        NETWORK SERVICE

Account Name:       TRxxxxxxxx$

Account Domain:     XXX

Logon ID:       0x3E4

Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:

```
Account Name:       cAdmin

Account Domain:     STUDENT.XXX.UK

Logon GUID:     {9c7e24da-6c6b-43d6-b222-48923be0c224}
```

Target Server:

```
Target Server Name: AD1.student.XXX.uk

Additional Information: ldap/AD1.student.XXX.uk
```

Process Information:

```
Process ID:     0x1520

Process Name:       C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
```

Network Information:

```
Network Address:    -

Port:           -
```

This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command.

==================================================
 
Second connection, ‘c’ is shown as the account this is repeated upto 7 times

============================================

A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:

```
Security ID:        NETWORK SERVICE

Account Name:       TRxxxxxx$

Account Domain:     XXX

Logon ID:       0x3E4

Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:

```
Account Name:       c

Account Domain:     

Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Target Server:

```
Target Server Name: AD2.student.XXX.uk

Additional Information: AD2.student.XXX.uk
```

Process Information:

```
Process ID:     0x1520

Process Name:       C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
```

Network Information:

```
Network Address:    -

Port:           -
```

This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command.

=====================================================

if any one has any advice or experience in this area, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: it seems the subsequent event log entries match the number of groups the user is a member of, we then do a look up for each group to find out what groups each group is in so we can import the whole tree.  just not sure why it goes off to a secondary AD and logs it as account name 'C'

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the identical problem.
Wireshark shows that the username in the bindRequest goes from double-byte encoded to quad-byte encoded fairly randomly.

e.g. 
"Craig" looks like this in packets when successful: `C\0r\0a\0i\0g\0`

In later bindRequests
"Craig" looks like `C\0\0\0r\0\0\0a\0\0\0i\0\0\0g\0\0\0`

In the server logs the user name is "C" because string functions on the server correctly interpret `C\0\0\0` as a null-terminated 1-character Unicode string.

Looks like a .Net bug, and in my experience possibly triggered by `SendRequest` that utilizes `PageResultRequestControl`